# What's the difference between StreamCallback and QueryCallback in Siddhi?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

There are many callbacks in siddhi, I want to know the difference between them.
Like, when we shall use streamCallback and when we shall use queryCallback.

I can't find any document about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Query callbacks are used to listen to the outputs of a specific query. On the other hand, when you use the StreamCallback, it's not bound to a specific query and can receive outputs from multiple queries (multiple queries can output to the same stream).

eg:

```
from profileStream 
select name, email
insert into outStream;

from alertStream
select name, mailAddress as email
insert into outStream;
```

If you add a query callback, you'd be adding it to one of these queries. But when you add a stream callback, you can add it for the outStream, which will give you the results of both queries.

Comment: thanks. For QueryCallback receive API,
receive(long timeStamp, Event[] inEvents, Event[] removeEvents);
inEvents, i can understand
but what is the removeEvents?
And why here need timeStamp, there is a timestamp in each Event, the timeStamp is the time of the callback be called?